# Angular Performance Degrading after Refreshing Data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've just started getting to grips with AngularJS, but I've found that my application runs into performance issues after a few minutes.

**Edit: It seems this only happens in IE11**

I have a page that imports a JSON array every 1 minute as follows:

```
$http.get('http://localhost/statuscheck.php?rnd' + new Date().getTime()).
        success(function (data) {

            $scope.statuschecks = data;
            $scope.onlinecount = parseInt(0);
            $scope.offlinecount = parseInt(0);
            $scope.totalchecks = parseInt(0);
            $scope.disabledcount = parseInt(0);
            $scope.checkcomplete = false;


            angular.forEach($scope.statuschecks, function (obj) {


                $http.get('http://localhost/monitoring_test.php?websiteID=' + obj.websiteID + '&rnd' + new Date().getTime()).
                        success(function (data) {

                            if (data.status == 'Online') {
                                $scope.onlinecount = parseInt($scope.onlinecount) + 1;
                            } else if (data.status == 'Offline') {
                                $scope.offlinecount = parseInt($scope.offlinecount) + 1;
                                sitesdownarr.push(obj.websiteID);
                            }

                            $scope.totalchecks = parseInt($scope.totalchecks) + 1;

                            if ($scope.totalchecks == $scope.statuschecks.length) {
                                $scope.checkcomplete = true;
                            }

                        });


            });

        });
```

Then I use the $scope.tasks object on the page to show some information. As this data changes regularly, I used $timeout to re-run the http.get to import the data again.

I was intending to have the browser window open all day, watching the page change as the data changes. However, after a few minute the browser window will grind to a halt due to a long running script. It seems that things bog down after just a few refreshes of the data.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: This code in and of itself shouldn't be the problem.  Are you registering watchers on this data or using $compile somewhere?

Comment: I have apps with data constantly refreshing that sty open for days sometimes. Not enough shown to even guess what your issues are

Comment: I have updated the question to include the code I'm using. This is operating within a function of a boostrap/angular dashboard that I bought online.

Is there a way that I can monitor how many objects are currently in memory, or other monitoring available so I can see where/why things slow down?

Comment: Out of curiosity, I checked the same page in Chrome (instead of IE11) and it works fine. Are there any known problems with IE11 that could cause this?